# SSL Certificate elucidation

Tags: ssl

Sorry for this stupid question but:

If I want develop an website that work over https (for login and registration purpose) and I want to test it I have to buy an SSL certificate or I can home-made it for private purpose?

Thank to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure application server for SSL. Different application servers have different configurations.
Choose your application server first.

Try this:

http://robsnotebook.com/xampp-ssl-encrypt-passwords

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. I use XAMPP so I use Apache as web server